# how do i retrieve input values from different websites without knowing the id or class name of the input field beforehand?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a password manager of my own and I've come to a dead end.
I would like my app, which is a chrome extension to get the values from fields like "password" "username" and "email" when clicking "log in" or "register". The issue is that not all sites have the same ids, classes or names for the html fields that hold these values.
Any ideas how can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

"Password Manager" sounds like a nice euphemism for "want to steal people's passwords".

All the same, on form submit you could just look for any fields that are `type="password"`. If there is one then you likely need one or all the other fields for authentication. At that point you'd likely just check the count of the other fields that are `type="text"`, and if it's `1` then the other field is your username, if it's not `1` you're going to have to do some fuzzy logic.

Comment: it does sound like that i guess. but it's for personal use as part of my final bachelor thesis, probably should have provided some background. thanks for the answer